# How do I start one service in docker-compose without checking for or starting any dependencies?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

We are using docker-compose in our dev environment to start all the services.

Does any one know if I can start just 1 service using docker-compose without checking if dependencies are running or not (since I know they are running)?

```
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose-service1.yml  up
```

it gives an error: ERROR: Service ‘service1’ depends on service ‘service2’ which is undefined.

The yml file looks something like:

```
version: '2'
services:

  service1:
    build: ./service1
    dns: 192.168.1.100
    depends_on:
      - "service2"
    container_name: service1
```

I just want to start service1 since I know all the dependencies are already running.

Comment: How are the services defined to depend on each other? Is this `depends_on` or `links`?

Comment: If other services are running and you want to restart one container, you can use `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml restart service1`

Comment: @PressingOnAlways, yml file uses depends_on for defining dependencies. I updated the question.

Comment: @Ayushya, your solution worked great. Why don't you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If other services are running and you want to restart only one, you can use

```sh
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml restart service1
```

**Edit:**

Regarding error:

> ERROR: Service ‘service1’ depends on service ‘service2’ which is
>   undefined.

It is because the `docker-compose.yml` which is used to `up` the services is not acceptable to docker-compose. First the yml file is compiled (the point of failure in our case)  to see if everything is as per proper syntax, and then it is executed.

Comment: @user674669 I've updated answer by explaining the cause of error you were seeing, if there is anything else that could be added to improve this answer, please let me know.

Comment: I just wanted to start a service (not restart it) so `docker compose -f docker-compose.ci.yml up db` did the job